CMFCButton with transparent background
I have developed a class that subclasses from CMFCButton. I load three PNG images (with transparent zones) to the button foreground in the DrawButton function for three states:

Normal
Hovered
Pushed

Everything works ok, except artefacts after mouse hover/pushed, it seems like new button image draws on the top of old button image during the mouse events.
Logically I understand that proper clear function is absent, but I don't know how to redraw the image on transparent background or clear to the previous image state properly, help me please to understand the technique and find a solution to redraw the image on fully transparent background.
Here is DrawButton function code:
void CAlphaButton::DrawButton(HDC hDestDC)
{
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(rc);
    int nWidth = rc.Width();
    int nHeight = rc.Height();

    HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDestDC);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDestDC, nWidth, nHeight);
    HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);

    // Here i can't achive transparent backgroud color (or i need to clear the old image properly)
    //HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));// i need transparent
    //SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
    //FillRect(hDC, &rc, hbr);
    //DeleteObject(hbr);


    // redraw accord to mouse events
    if (m_bDisable) { }

    else if (m_bDown) {

        if (!m_png_Pushed.IsNull())
        {
            m_png_Pushed.Draw(hDC, rc);
        }

    }
    else if (m_bOver) {

        if (!m_png_Over.IsNull())
        {
            m_png_Over.Draw(hDC, rc);
        }

    }
    else {

        if (!m_png_Normal.IsNull())
        {
            m_png_Normal.Draw(hDC, rc);
        }
    }

    if (m_bSingleImage)
    {
        if (!m_idb_image.IsNull())
        {
            m_idb_image.Draw(hDC, rc);
        }
    }

    //AlphaBlend
    BLENDFUNCTION blend;
    blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blend.BlendFlags = 0;
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    AlphaBlend(hDestDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, blend);

    // Clean
    SelectObject(hDC, hOldBitmap);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hDC);

}


See if adding m_bTransparent = TRUE; in the constructor of the class you derived from CMFCButton is helpful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-170#m_btransparent
